# Keep original data points when padding a signal with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following test data set:

```
testdf = pandas.DataFrame({'t': [datetime(2015, 1, 1, 10,  0),
                                 datetime(2015, 1, 1, 11, 32),
                                 datetime(2015, 1, 1, 12,  0)],
                           'val': [1, 2, 3]})
```

I would like to interpolate this data set using simple padding, such that I have a data point at least every 30 mins, while keeping the original data points.

An appropriate result would look like this:

```
't'                'val'
2015-01-01 10:00   1
2015-01-01 10:30   1
2015-01-01 11:00   1
2015-01-01 11:30   1
2015-01-01 11:32   2
2015-01-01 12:00   3
```

Which would be a good way of achieving this result, preferably using standard pandas methods?

I know of the `DataFrame.resample` method, but

a) I can't seem to find the right values of the `how` parameter to achieve the desired simple padding, and

b) I can't find a way to keep the original data points in the result.

Problem b) could of course be circumvented by manually adding the original data points to the resampled DataFrame, although I wouldn't call this a particularly neat solution.

Comment: At first I thought of using `reindex` with `method='bfill'`, but this does not keep the original data points, hence my proposed answer with `combine_first`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate an index with the missing timestamps and create a dataframe with `NaN` values. Then combine it with the `combine_first` method and fill in the `NaN` values:

```
idx = pandas.date_range(datetime(2015, 1, 1, 10, 0), datetime(2015, 1, 1, 12, 0), freq='30min')
df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.nan, index=idx, columns=['val'])

testdf.set_index('t', inplace=True)
testdf.combine_first(df).fillna(method='ffill')
```

The [documentation of the `combine_first` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) reads:

> Combine two DataFrame objects and default to non-null values in frame
>   calling the method. Result index columns will be the union of the
>   respective indexes and columns

The `ffill` method of the `fillna` method does the following ([source](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)):

> ffill: propagate last valid observation forward to next valid backfill