# pandas DataFrame resample from irregular timeseries index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

I want to resample a DataFrame to every five seconds, where the time stamps of the original data are irregular. Apologies if this looks like a duplicate question, but I have issues with the interpolation lining up to the timestamps of the data, which is why I include my DataFrame in this question. [The graph in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39730384/5816553) shows my desired results, but I cannot use the `traces` package suggested there. I use `pandas 0.19.0`.

Consider the following climb path of an aircraft ([as dict on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ZKx0YEyB)):

```
    Altitude        Time
1       0.00     0.00000
2    1000.00    16.45350
3    2000.00    33.19584
4    3000.00    50.25330
5    4000.00    67.64580
6    5000.00    85.38720
7    6000.00   103.56720
8    7000.00   122.29260
9    8000.00   141.61440
10   9000.00   161.59140
11   9999.67   182.27940
12  10000.30   182.33940
13  10000.30   199.76880
14  10000.30   199.82880
15  11000.00   221.67660
16  12000.00   244.36260
17  13000.00   267.93900
18  14000.00   292.46940
19  15000.00   318.01080
20  16000.00   344.36820
21  17000.00   371.32200
22  18000.00   398.91420
23  19000.00   427.19100
24  20000.00   456.24900
25  21000.00   486.38940
26  22000.00   517.91640
27  23000.00   550.96140
28  24000.00   585.65460
29  25000.00   622.12800
30  26000.00   660.35400
31  27000.00   700.37400
32  28000.00   742.39200
33  29000.00   786.57600
34  30000.00   833.13000
35  31000.00   882.09000
36  32000.00   933.46200
37  33000.00   987.40800
38  34000.00  1044.06000
39  35000.00  1103.85000
40  36000.00  1167.52200
41  36088.90  1173.39000
42  36089.60  1173.45000
43  36671.70  1216.60200
44  36672.40  1216.66200
45  38000.00  1295.80200
46  39000.00  1368.45000
47  40000.00  1458.00000
48  41000.00  1574.08200
49  42000.00  1730.97000
50  42231.00  1775.19600
```

### Tried solutions

**First,** I have tried resampling while keeping the original index intact, as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35918248/), so I could then linearly interpolate, but I found no method of interpolation that produces correct results (note the original time column that only matches at 16.45s):

```
df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], unit='s'), drop=False)
resample_index = pd.date_range(start=df.index[0], end=df.index[-1], freq='5s')
dummy_frame = pd.DataFrame(np.NaN, index=resample_index, columns=df.columns)
df.combine_first(dummy_frame).interpolate().iloc[:6]

                                 Time  Altitude
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000   0.000000       0.0
1970-01-01 00:00:05.000000   4.113375     250.0
1970-01-01 00:00:10.000000   8.226750     500.0
1970-01-01 00:00:15.000000  12.340125     750.0
1970-01-01 00:00:16.453500  16.453500    1000.0
1970-01-01 00:00:20.000000  20.639085    1250.0
```

**Second,** I tried resampling without keeping the original index, first down to 1s and then up to 5s, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39730730/5816553), but the interpolation values do not line up at the end of the data, nor do the altitude values (1000ft should be between 15 and 20 seconds). Just resampling to 1s already produces wrong results.

```
df.resample('1s').interpolate(method='linear').resample('5s').asfreq()

                       Time      Altitude
1970-01-01 00:00:00     0.0      0.000000
1970-01-01 00:00:05     5.0    137.174211
1970-01-01 00:00:10    10.0    274.348422
1970-01-01 00:00:15    15.0    411.522634
1970-01-01 00:00:20    20.0    548.696845
1970-01-01 00:00:25    25.0    685.871056
1970-01-01 00:00:30    30.0    823.045267
1970-01-01 00:00:35    35.0    960.219479
1970-01-01 00:00:40    40.0   1097.393690
1970-01-01 00:00:45    45.0   1234.567901
1970-01-01 00:00:50    50.0   1371.742112
1970-01-01 00:00:55    55.0   1508.916324
1970-01-01 00:01:00    60.0   1646.090535
1970-01-01 00:01:05    65.0   1783.264746
1970-01-01 00:01:10    70.0   1920.438957
1970-01-01 00:01:15    75.0   2057.613169
1970-01-01 00:01:20    80.0   2194.787380
1970-01-01 00:01:25    85.0   2331.961591
1970-01-01 00:01:30    90.0   2469.135802
1970-01-01 00:01:35    95.0   2606.310014
1970-01-01 00:01:40   100.0   2743.484225
1970-01-01 00:01:45   105.0   2880.658436
1970-01-01 00:01:50   110.0   3017.832647
1970-01-01 00:01:55   115.0   3155.006859
1970-01-01 00:02:00   120.0   3292.181070
1970-01-01 00:02:05   125.0   3429.355281
1970-01-01 00:02:10   130.0   3566.529492
1970-01-01 00:02:15   135.0   3703.703704
1970-01-01 00:02:20   140.0   3840.877915
1970-01-01 00:02:25   145.0   3978.052126
...                     ...           ...
1970-01-01 00:27:10  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:27:15  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:27:20  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:27:25  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:27:30  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:27:35  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:27:40  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:27:45  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:27:50  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:27:55  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:28:00  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:28:05  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:28:10  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:28:15  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:28:20  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:28:25  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:28:30  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:28:35  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:28:40  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:28:45  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:28:50  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:28:55  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:29:00  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:29:05  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:29:10  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:29:15  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:29:20  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:29:25  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:29:30  1458.0  40000.000000
1970-01-01 00:29:35  1458.0  40000.000000
```

### The Question

How can I go about resampling the original data to 5s while performing a correct interpolation? Am I just using the wrong interpolation method?

Comment: Try `data = data.resample('5s', how = 'last').interpolate()`

Comment: This doesn't work, e.g. at the 15s index the 'Time' column is then 16.45 and Altitude is 1000ft (i.e. the values of the original 16.45s index).

Comment: Maybe like this: `data = data.resample('1ms').interpolate('linear', how = 'last').resample('5s', how = 'last')` . So get a real high resolution first and then sample down again.

Comment: Doesn't work either. At the 15s index, Time is now 19.999. Also FYI, `how` seems to be deprecated in future versions: `FutureWarning: how in .resample() is deprecated the new syntax is .resample(...).last()`

Comment: I just keep `Time` around as a validation column, you are right that my focus is on the remaining columns. Though the 970ft are closer to the solution, it is still wrong: At 15s, the aircraft should be at `1000*(15/16.45) = 911.85` feet. I cannot paste the resulting DataFrame into this comment, but note for instance that for your last suggestion the Altitude at the 0s Timestamp is already 242.54ft. I think the `last` method is not the correct approach, but cannot back it up other than by pointing out why your suggestions don't work. I cannot find documentation on how `how` works.

Comment: Ok my last attempt :D `data = data.resample('0.1ms').interpolate('time').resample('5s').mean()`

Comment: No I'm sorry it doesn't produce correct results. I also do not see the intention of the `mean` at the end for this problem. Thank you very much for your input so far though! `'0.1ms'` is not a valid frequency btw, but e.g. `'1ms'` is.

Comment: `0.1ms` works for me though. The mean was not intended. There should have been a `ffill()`. When I plot both lines they are 99.9% the same and 15s = 911f.

Comment: I don't know why `0.1ms` throws an error for me but not for you. Unfortunately, your suggestion caused my results to be off slightly still. However, the `time` interpolation option was something I hadn't considered before and it seems to produce exact results using the first tried method in my question. I'm gonna post that as an answer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166539/discussion-between-alarik-and-martin-schmelzer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some help from @Martin Schmelzer (thanks!) I found the first suggested method from the question to be working, when applying `time` as the `method` parameter for pandas' interpolation method:

```
resample_index = pd.date_range(start=df.index[0], end=df.index[-1], freq='5s')
dummy_frame = pd.DataFrame(np.NaN, index=resample_index, columns=df.columns)
df.combine_first(dummy_frame).interpolate('time').iloc[:6]

                               Altitude     Time
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000     0.000000   0.0000
1970-01-01 00:00:05.000000   303.886711   5.0000
1970-01-01 00:00:10.000000   607.773422  10.0000
1970-01-01 00:00:15.000000   911.660133  15.0000
1970-01-01 00:00:16.453500  1000.000000  16.4535
1970-01-01 00:00:20.000000  1211.828215  20.0000
```

I can then resample this to 5s or whatever and the results are exact.

```
df.combine_first(dummy_frame).interpolate('time').resample('5s').asfreq().head()
                        Altitude  Time
1970-01-01 00:00:00     0.000000   0.0
1970-01-01 00:00:05   303.886711   5.0
1970-01-01 00:00:10   607.773422  10.0
1970-01-01 00:00:15   911.660133  15.0
1970-01-01 00:00:20  1211.828215  20.0
```

So in the end it turns out I was just using the wrong interpolation method after all.

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem surprisingly difficult. Especially if the set of interpolated values are not easily defined by date_range(). There are a number of gotchas:

1. Duplicates in the original data set will propagate to duplicates in the interpolated data frame. That is undesired behavior, and results in interpolated arrays of different lengths.
2. If your interpolation value is already in the data frame, a duplicate will be added.
3. You've got to be sure you merge data frames and then sort appropriately.

This code works for me:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

    def interpolate_into(df, interpolate_keys, index_name, columns):

        # Downselect to only those columns necessary
        # Also, remove duplicated values in the data frame. Eye roll.
        df = df[[index_name] + columns]
        df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=[index_name], keep="first")
        df = df.set_index(index_name)

        # Only interpolate into values that don't already exist. This is not handled manually.
        needed_interpolate_keys = [i for i in interpolate_keys if i not in df.index]

        # Create a dummy DF that has the x or time values we want to interpolate into.
        dummy_frame = pd.DataFrame(np.NaN, index=needed_interpolate_keys, columns=df.columns)
        dummy_frame[index_name] = pd.to_datetime(needed_interpolate_keys)
        dummy_frame = dummy_frame.set_index(index_name)

        # Combine the dataframes, sort, interpolate, downselect.
        df = dummy_frame.combine_first(df)
        df = df.sort_values(by=index_name, ascending=True)
        df = df.interpolate()
        df = df[df.index.isin(interpolate_keys)]
        return df
```

`df` is the original data frame.

`interpolated_keys` is the list of "x" values to interpolate new values for.

`index_name` is the name of the column of those keys

`columns` are the additional columns you want to interpolate values for.